# MessageOpened not woring on Android and iOS 10

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

I have implemented Salesforce SDK on iOS & Android, the `MessageOpened` is ok after iOS 9 device received push notification.

But it's not working with iOS 10 device & Anroid device. Any one has faced this issue?

Comment: Do you have `setEtAnalyticsEnabled(true)` in the `ETPushConfig` that you're passing to `configureSdk()` on Android?  You _must_ enable analytics in order for the SDK to collect any analytics data and send it to the Marketing Cloud servers.

Comment: is that option really affect? I will try

Comment: Yes.  If you fail to enable analytics in your ETPushConfig then you should have no expectation of receiving analytics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to my original question in comments:

Please enable analytics when you call `configureSdk()`.  This will result in analytics data being transmitted to the MarketingCloud servers.

Setting an OpenDirect delegate will have no bearing on the analytics being transmitted as it merely provides a delegate for the message to be displayed *after* the notification has been displayed and opened.

Android Docs regarding Analytics: [ENABLING ANALYTICS](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/analytics.html)

iOS Docs regarding Analytics: [ENABLING ANALYTICS](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/analytics.html)

Comment: ya, analytics enabling solved the problem. Thank you